# Save updatable variable into another that will not change

Tags: python-3.x, variables

maybe it's very stupid question, but i can't figure it out yet.

```
def check(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    value = soup.find_all('td')
    valstr = str(value)
    ssp = valstr.split("$")
    ssp2 = ssp[1].split(" ")

    check.price = float(ssp2[0])
    check.price_old = check.price

    return check.price
```

in this code i want to save price_old so when price will update from 15 to 18 i want price_old to remain 15, when price will update from 18 to 21 price_old must be 18 an so on.

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python by default uses references to assign one object to another, in most cases it's acceptable. In your case when you wan to have independent copy use `deepcopy()`:

```
import copy
...
check.price_old = copy.deepcopy(check.price)
...
```

Now `price_old` will keep its value until next assignment. Any change to `price` wont affect `price_old`.

Comment: thanks, that solved my first problem, but now i have to update price_old ,
e.g. price = 1
price_old = 1

price = 2
price_old = 1

price = 3
price_old = 2

And so on

Comment: As I understand you just need to change order of these two assignments, so first you update `price_old` then `price`:
    check.price_old = copy.deepcopy(check.price)
    check.price = float(ssp2[0])

Comment: i can't because in that case check.price is not defined yet so price_old cant copy it

Comment: well, you should have some initial value for both `price` and `price_old`, otherwise your variables are uninitialized what is at least bad coding style and may cause undefined behavior, crashes, etc.

Comment: i know but i cant initial value for price and price_old because they are function attributes so i cant initialize it outside function and if i will initialize it inside function they will be 0 at every start of that function

Comment: yes, you can initialize them outside: `setattr(check, 'price', 0)` or `check.price = 0`
See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Python-function-attributes